# Memory Leak, safe to save?

Tags: mysql

Would it be safe to save SQL data from memory if the program is having a memory leak and peeks 100% memory and 100% cpu usage?

Comment: 100 % memory usage doesn't necessarily mean that there's a memory leak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a memory leak doesn't corrupt the data, it only grabs more and more memory without releasing it. so you would not have a problem with integrity, because the old data, are not  released, the new data are the current ones.

cpu time at 100 pro cent, will make it difficult to save any data, because you will not get any cpu time to do so.

Fix your problems, the<y are all manageable and then you will not have any bothers or see if there is an update

Comment: Your answer only applies to the case where memory blocks are stopped being used but not released. There are other possibilities where memory is only partially stopped being used which could cause inconsistencies. From the outside it's not distinguishable

Comment: Your memory when it reaches 100 % gets memory from the harddrive file and uses that to "increase" the memory, which swaps data from memory to the harddrive and back, that has nothing to do with a memory leak, this will increase till the max allowed by the operating system and then generates an error. I had this with crystak reports, which would relase the accumulated memory instead increased it with evry report generated, that is a memory leak